# Preventing download of video files from outside the web server (via .htaccess)?

Tags: file, .htaccess, download

I've got video files stored as:

```
www.example.com/video_files/abc.flv
```

My application uses FlowPlayer which streams this video file to the end user.

How can I restrict access to these files only to the application within the server and prevent ppl from typing in the url/file link directly and downloading the file?

Comment: @All - its a similar idea to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211832/preventing-direct-download-of-sqlite-file-using-htaccess but for all files in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't, if the media is streamed unprotected.  People with packet sniffers will always be able to dump the stream as it's sent to their browser.

If this is really important to you, you should investigate a DRM solution.  (But note that DRM is not unbreakable either.)

Comment: but why cant I just "serve" the local machine via some rules in .htaccess? The FlowPlayer application reads the file and streams it accordingly. If someone wants to copy it using the method you describe, that's fine...

Comment: Oh, is it just a machine on your LAN (or the server itself) that needs access?  If so, just restrict by IP using allow/deny and a `<FilesMatch>` directive.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it.
The best thing, that you can do, add to link some hash and timestamp.
For example www.example.com/video_files/abc.flv => www.example.com/video_files/12345678901234567890123456789012/12345678/abc.flv

12345678901234567890123456789012 - is hash
12345678 - is timestamp, to which that link will be valid.

as hash function you can use for example something like:
hash = md5(abc.flv12345678somesecretkey)

After reciving request, webserver must check hash and timestamp and after that output file to user or throw an error.

For each user you must generate it's own url with a small lifetime.
User can't redestribute url's because it's expires very quuickly.

PS, sorry for my bad english